# Dynamic call of shortcode with parameters

Tags: wordpress, parameters, woocommerce, shortcode

I have this function:

```
function test_q($atts){
    $args = shortcode_atts(array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
                    'columns' => 4,
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => array( 'mugs' ),
                           ),
                   array(
                       'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
                       'field'    => 'slug',
                       'terms'    => array( 'football' ),
                          ),
                    ),
             ), $atts);
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                   woocommerce_product_loop_start();
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
                    woocommerce_product_loop_end();
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
            woocommerce_reset_loop();
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
```

}
add_shortcode('testasd', 'test_q');

I want to pass dynamic parameters to 'mugs' and 'football' with the shortcode. I am filtering products by category and tag. This function is working fine but I want to pass those two parameters through shortcode to make it dynamic.
I need to call this shortcode each time with different 'mugs' and 'football' term. For example 't-shirts' and 'basketball'. How will i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily via extracting the shortcode and passing the values via $atts from the shortcode.

After your arguments , you can pass it like the following ,

```
if($args['tax_query']['taxonomy'] == 'product_cat'){
    $args['tax_query']['terms'] = $atts['terms_cat'];
}
if($args['tax_query']['taxonomy'] == 'product_tag'){
    $args['tax_query']['terms'] = $atts['terms_tag'];
}
```

Then add 2 parameters in the shortcode,

```
[testasd terms_cat='t-shirts' terms_tag='basketball']
```